# How to run executable(need su permission) code in android application on a partly rooted device

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, root

I have a partly rooted android device that means the root access is only available in adb shell. I can not fully root that device.

I am working on an app where I need to access the location which requires root access. Its a NDK code. I have make an executable and placed that executable in system folder. Then I have given the permissions with 'chmod 777 executable'. I am able to run that executable from adb shell with su permissions.
Now, I want to run same executable from within android. Please let me know how can I give root access within my android application to run the executable with code like `su -c executable`.

Please note that I can not install Magisk or SuperSu in that device. This is not acceptable solution. But I can do anything from adb shell. I have searched a lot and I have a solution which may work:

- Create a new user `adb shell pm create-user name`
- Give su permissions to that user. I didn't find a way to give su permissions to user.
- Run the application from newly created user space. I am not sure how it will be done.

I am not sure if it will be a successfully solution if I would know above things.

I shall be very thankful to you if you will help me.

Best Regards,

Vatish

Comment: `I need to access the location which requires root access` In user build you need to adhere to SE policies.

Comment: What about creating a folder with required permissions through `shell` and put the executable there?

Comment: The executable is actually trying to get some data from `dev/diag` port and it requires su permissions. Putting a executable in a folder with su permissions doesn't help. I have also tried giving diag port global permissions i.e. `chmod 777 dev/diag` but it also didn't help.

Comment: I have an idea: Is it possible if we can run adb shell from within the android app. If yes, then I can get su permissions within adb by running 'su' command and then I can run executable. Please suggest.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Please explain a little more about how we can adhere SE policies for an app and Is it will enable access on diag port without fully rooting the device?